# Return all properties in JS object to "empty" state

Tags: javascript, object, truncate

I wonder if there's a utility function in any framework like jQuery to truncate a JS object (there is more than one possible result, not sure what is the most useful yet):

```
{ // original object
    foo: "bar",
    arr: [1, 2, 3],
    sub: {a: 4, b: 5, subsub: {c: 6}} }

{ // truncated, variant 1
    foo: "",
    arr: [],
    sub: {} }

{ // truncated, variant 2
    foo: "",
    arr: [],
    sub: {subsub: {}} }

{ // truncated, variant 3
    foo: "",
    arr: [],
    sub: {a: 0, b: 0, subsub: {c: 0}} }
```

If no, is there a solution more clever than to recursively iterate over all properties, check types and remove / reset if necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call the constructor for each property to create an empty object of the same type.

```
for (var k in obj) {
    obj[k] = obj[k] && obj[k].constructor();
}
```

This will also return numbers to 0, booleans to false, dates to now, and regexps to empty (but NaNs remain NaN).

To do this recursively, retaining object-valued properties but emptying them out too (variant 3):

```
function truncate(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        var ctor = obj[k] && obj[k].constructor;
        if      (ctor === Object) truncate(obj[k]);
        else if (ctor)            obj[k] = ctor();
    }
}
```

To eliminate numbers (variant 2), add a check:

```
function truncate(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        var ctor = obj[k] && obj[k].constructor;
        if      (ctor === Object) truncate(obj[k]);
        else if (ctor === Number) delete obj[k];
        else if (ctor)            obj[k] = ctor();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Great idea, but won't work with `undefined` nor `null` values.

Comment: Nice and concise, thanks! `Date`s are reset to *now*, functions are truncated as well. `NaN` and `Infinity` are reset to `0`, which makes sense as both are of type `number`.

Comment: Yes, and for some reason regexps get reset to `/(?:)/`.

Comment: `//` can't be used to create an empty RegExp because it's obviously used for one-line comments. `/()/` could be used, but `()` creates a capture group. Thus, `/(?:)/` is used (`?:` means non-capture group).

Comment: Your variant 2 doesn't work, there's no variable `val` and it doesn't seem to recurse into objects even after I add `var val = obj[k];`

Comment: Sorry, I "fixed" it and broke it, OK now.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for OMIT, part of [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#omit).

> omit_.omit(object, *keys)  Return a copy of the object, filtered to
>   omit the blacklisted keys (or array of keys). Alternatively accepts a
>   predicate indicating which keys to omit.
>
> _.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'userid');
>   => {name: 'moe', age: 50}
>   _.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, function(value, key, object) {   return _.isNumber(value); });
>   => {name: 'moe', userid: 'moe1'}

Comment: This would seem to be solving a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.prototype.clear=function(){
    for (prop in this){
        if (typeof this[prop]==='string') this[prop]='';
        else if (this[prop] instanceof Array) this[prop]=[];
        else{
            this[prop]={}//variant 1
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

.

```
var obj={
    foo:"bar", 
    arr:[1,2,3],
    sub:{b:4,c:5,subsub:{e:6}}
}

obj.clear()//returns {foo:"",arr:[],sub:{}}
```